# Failed to migrate GCE VM to GKE

Tags: google-anthos

I was following this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/anthos/docs/migrate-gce-to-gke) to migrate a GCE Debian 9 VM to GKE with Migrate for Anthos, but when I apply the generated YAML to my GKE cluster, the Pod failed to be scheduled, the events include this error:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  52s (x14 over 7m59s)  default-scheduler  pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
```

Seems the PVC was failed to be provisioned because `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "v2k-csi-gce-disk" not found`:

```
$ kpvcs-describe my-app-pvc
Name:          my-app-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  v2k-csi-gce-disk
Status:        Pending
...
Events:
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  103s (x9 over 5m14s)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "v2k-csi-gce-disk" not found
```

Here is the generated YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-app-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: v2k-csi-gce-disk
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50G

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: vls-pv-vls-c7c8-dagang-test
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 50G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    # Name of pd
    pdName: vls-c7c8-dagang-test
  volumeMode: Block
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: vls-pvc-vls-c7c8-dagang-test
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  volumeName: vls-pv-vls-c7c8-dagang-test
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50G
  volumeMode: Block

---
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  serviceName: "my-app-svc"
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: lister
        image: anthos-migrate.gcr.io/vls-runimg:v0.9.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volumes
          mountPath: /volumes
        volumeDevices:
        - name: vls-c7c8-dagang-test
          devicePath: /devices/000-vls-c7c8-dagang-test

        env:
          - name: "HC_BOOT_DEVICE_NAME"
            value: "000-vls-c7c8-dagang-test"
          - name: "HC_DEVICES_DIR"
            value: "/devices"
          - name: "HC_DEVICES_LIST_DIR"
            value: "/volumes"
          - name: "HC_RUNNER_PARAMS"
            value: "listdevs"
      - name: init
        image: anthos-migrate.gcr.io/v2k-init:v0.9.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: "HC_BLOCKDEV_MODE"
            value: "true"
          - name: "HC_TRIM_MOUNTS"
            value: "false"
          - name: "HC_VOLUME_PATH"
            value: "/volumes"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: volumes
          mountPath: /volumes
        - name: vlsdata
          mountPath: /vlsdata
          mountPropagation: Bidirectional
        - name: lvmdata
          mountPath: /run/lvm
        - name: udevdata
          mountPath: /run/udev
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: anthos-migrate.gcr.io/v2k-run:v0.9.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vlsdata
          mountPath: /vlsdata
          mountPropagation: Bidirectional
        - name: cgroups
          mountPath: /sys/fs/cgroup
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /code/ready.sh
      volumes:
      - name: vls-c7c8-dagang-test
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: vls-pvc-vls-c7c8-dagang-test
          readOnly: false

      - name: volumes
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: vlsdata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-app-pvc
          readOnly: false
      - name: lvmdata
        hostPath:
          path: /run/lvm
          type: Directory
      - name: udevdata
        hostPath:
          path: /run/udev
          type: Directory
      - name: cgroups
        hostPath:
          path: /sys/fs/cgroup
          type: Directory
```

Comment: Maybe because of a different apiVersion from "storageclass.storage.k8s.io" or maybe storage api is not enable. Did you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it fails due to missing Migrate for Anthos GKE application on the cluster (v2k-csi-gce-disk StorageClass is part of this app).  The pre-requisites for migrations of GCE VMs are summarized in [Configuring a cluster](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/anthos/docs/configuring-a-cluster) and [Creating a Migrate for Anthos configuration](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/anthos/docs/creating-migrate-anthos-configuration) pages. Indeed, current version of docs seems to be a bit implicit on the pre-requisites, will follow-up on that.